# DatePicker style container not

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, expo

hey everybody I'm still new to the react native world.
I'm using expo and the project is in typescript

I get this error when I try style date picker

eg
<DatePicker
style={styles.datepicker}.  <-- error happens here

Type '{ style: { width: number; marginTop: number; }; date: string; mode: string; placeholder: string; format: string; minDate: string; maxDate: string; confirmBtnText: string; cancelBtnText: string; customStyles: { ...; }; onDateChange: (date: any) => void; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.
Property 'style' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.ts(2322)

````
import React, { use state } from 'react';
import { Platform, View, Button,Text ,StyleSheet} from 'react-native';

export default function DatePicker () {
    const [date, setDate] = useState('09-10-2020');

    return (
      
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Text style={styles.title}>
            React Native Date Picker – To Pick the Date using Native Calendar
          </Text>
          <DatePicker
            style={styles.datePickerStyle}
            date={date} //initial date from state
            mode="date" //The enum of date, datetime and time
            placeholder="select date"
            format="DD-MM-YYYY"
            minDate="01-01-2016"
            maxDate="01-01-2019"
            confirmBtnText="Confirm"
            cancelBtnText="Cancel"
            customStyles={{
              dateIcon: {
                //display: 'none',
                position: 'absolute',
                left: 0,
                top: 4,
                marginLeft: 0,
              },
              dateInput: {
                marginLeft: 36,
              },
            }}
            onDateChange={(date) => {
              setDate(date);
            }}
          />
        </View>
    );
  };

  const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      flex: 1,
      padding: 10,
      justifyContent: 'center',
      alignItems: 'center',
    },
    title: {
      textAlign: 'center',
      fontSize: 20,
      fontWeight: 'bold',
      padding: 20,
    },
    datePickerStyle: {
      width: 200,
      marginTop: 20,
    },
  }); ```
````

Comment: You don't seem to have a DatePicker imported? And RN is thinking you are to trying  instantiate a component called DatePicker but this component does not know of any of the props passed.

Comment: yes it is imported sorry i just did not copy the complete code into the question my apologies

Comment: found the issue the naming of my function was the issue as it was named exactly the same as the package just changed it to datepickercomponent

Comment: Ah there you go. Nice one.